# What is the 2nd argument for the iter function in Python?

Tags: python, arguments, iterable, built-in

Let's consider a file:

```
$ echo -e """This is a foo bar sentence .\nAnd this is the first txtfile in the corpus .""" > test.txt
$ cat test.txt 
This is a foo bar sentence .
And this is the first txtfile in the corpus .
```

And when I want to read the file by character, I can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/25071590/610569:

```
>>> fin = open('test.txt')
>>> while fin.read(1):
...     fin.seek(-1,1)
...     print fin.read(1),
... 
T h i s   i s   a   f o o   b a r   s e n t e n c e   . 
A n d   t h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   t x t f i l e   i n   t h e   c o r p u s   .
```

But using while loop might look a little unpythonic esp. when i use `fin.read(1)` to check for EOF and then backtrack in-order to read the current byte. And so I can do something like this [How to read a single character at a time from a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2988211/610569):

```
>>> import functools
>>> fin = open('test.txt')
>>> fin_1byte = iter(functools.partial(fin.read, 1), '')
>>> for c in fin_1byte:
...     print c,
... 
T h i s   i s   a   f o o   b a r   s e n t e n c e   . 
A n d   t h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   t x t f i l e   i n   t h e   c o r p u s   .
```

But when I tried it without the second argument, it throws a `TypeError`:

```
>>> fin = open('test.txt')
>>> fin_1byte = functools.partial(fin.read, 1)
>>> for c in iter(fin_1byte):
...     print c,
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'functools.partial' object is not iterable
```

**What is the 2nd argument in `iter`?** The docs don't say much either: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter and https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#iter

---

As per the doc:

> Return an iterator object. The first argument is interpreted very differently depending on the presence of the second argument. Without a second argument, object must be a collection object which supports the iteration protocol (the **iter**() method), or it must support the sequence protocol (the **getitem**() method with integer arguments starting at 0). If it does not support either of those protocols, TypeError is raised. If the second argument, sentinel, is given, then object must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call object with no arguments for each call to its **next**() method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, StopIteration will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

I guess the docs require some "decrypting":

- Without a second argument, object must be a collection object which supports the iteration protocol (the **iter**() method)

Does that mean it needs to come from `collections`? Or is that as long as the object has an `__iter__()`, that's okay?

- , or it must support the sequence protocol (the **getitem**() method with integer arguments starting at 0)

That's rather cryptic. So does that means it tries to see whether the sequence is indexed and hence query-able and that the index must starts from 0? Does it also mean that the indices need to be sequential, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and not something like 0, 2, 8, 13, ...?

- If it does not support either of those protocols, TypeError is raised.

Yes, this part, I do understand =)

- If the second argument, sentinel, is given, then object must be a callable object.

Okay, now this gets a little sci-fi. Is it just a terminology in Python to call something a `sentinel`? What does `sentinel` mean Pythonically? And "callable object" like it's a function and not type object?

- The iterator created in this case will call object with no arguments for each call to its next() method;

This part i don't really get it, maybe an example would help.

- if the value returned is equal to sentinel, StopIteration will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

Okay, so `sentinel` here refers to some breaking criteria?

**Can someone help to decipher/clarify the meaning of the above points about `iter`?**

Comment: It looks to me like the docs explain exactly what the second argument is. The explanation starts at "If the second argument, sentinel, is given" and continues to the end of the paragraph. What didn't you get?

Comment: Docs can be useful: [iter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter)

Comment: Never mind the dupe's Java tag; it applies generally.

Comment: Overall, you seem to have several questions in your question, making this too broad.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 i'm asking what does the doc in the `iter` means since the document isn't self-explanatory to me, more specifically, the elusive second argument `''` that makes the function work.

Comment: If @Antti hadn't nuked my dupe target, you would have an answer to exactly that. I'm not sure why he did that.

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666508/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-a-sentinel-does-in-java-or-how-it-works?

Comment: Yes. There is your answer of what a sentinel is.

Comment: The second form of `iter(func, sentinel)` just repeatedly calls `func()` until it returns `sentinel` then `iter()` raises `StopIteration`. That mean `func()` will generally be stateful or random. In your example, `fin.read` will return 1 character at a time and returns the empty string `''` when it reaches the end of the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With one argument, `iter` must be given an object that has the `__iter__` special method, **or** `__getitem__` special method. If neither of them exists, `iter` **will** raise an error

```
>>> iter(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

There are 2 protocols for iteration. The old protocol relies on calling `__getitem__` for successive integers from 0 until one that raises `IndexError`. The new protocol relies on the iterator that is returned from `__iter__`.

In Python 2, `str` doesn't even have the `__iter__` special method:

```
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160914] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'abc'.__iter__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__iter__'
```

yet it is still iterable:

```
>>> iter('abc')
<iterator object at 0x7fcee9e89390>
```

To make your custom class iterable, you need to have **either** `__iter__` or `__getitem__` that raises `IndexError` for non-existent items:

```
class Foo:
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(range(5))

class Bar:
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i >= 5:
            raise IndexError
        return i
```

Using these:

```
>>> list(iter(Foo()))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(iter(Bar()))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Usually explicit `iter` is not needed as `for` loops and methods that expect *iterables* will create an iterator implicitly:

```
>>> list(Foo())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for i in Bar():
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

With the 2 argument form, the first argument must be a function or an object that implements `__call__`. The first argument is called without arguments; the return values are yielded from the iterator. The iteration stops when the value returned from the function call on that iteration equals the given **sentinel** value, as if by:

```
value = func()
if value == sentinel:
    return
else:
    yield value
```

For example, to get values on a die *before* we throw 6,

```
>>> import random
>>> throw = lambda: random.randint(1, 6)
>>> list(iter(throw, 6))
[3, 2, 4, 5, 5]
>>> list(iter(throw, 6))
[1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4]
```

To clarify it further, the given function (or the given object with `__call__` special method) is called without arguments for each time the `next()` is used on the iterator:

```
>>> def throw_die():
...     die = random.randint(1, 6)
...     print("returning {}".format(die))
...     return die
...
>>> throws = iter(throw_die, 6)
>>> next(throws)
returning 2
2
>>> next(throws)
returning 4
4
>>> next(throws)
returning 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

(i.e. `throw` is called as `throw()` and if the returned value didn't equal to 6, it is yielded).

Or in the case of

```
>>> fin_1byte = iter(functools.partial(fin.read, 1), '')
>>> for c in fin_1byte:
...     print c,
```

reading from a file at the end-of-file returns the *empty string* (or empty bytes if it was a binary file):

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> fin = StringIO(u'ab')
>>> fin.read(1)
u'a'
>>> fin.read(1)
u'b'
>>> fin.read(1)
u''
```

If not yet at the end of file, one character would be returned.

This can be used to also make an endless iterator from repeated function calls:

```
>>> dice = iter(throw, 7)
```

Since the value returned can never be equal to 7, the iterator runs forever. A common idiom is to use an anonymous `object` to make sure that the comparison wouldn't succeed for any conceivable value

```
>>> dice = iter(throw, object())
```

Because

```
>>> object() != object()
True
```

---

Note, that the word **sentinel** is commonly used for a value that is used as an end marker in some data, and that doesn't occur naturally within the data, as in [this Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666508/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-a-sentinel-does-in-java-or-how-it-works).